# Google Maps API not working correctly in Vue

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vuejs3

I'm having issues with using the Google Maps API in Vue. One of the problems I'm having is removing markers from the map (it's not the only problem but the easiest to target for now).

I have a minimum reproduction repo at https://github.com/chipit24/google-maps-vue-issues. All the relevant code is in `App.vue` (if you pull it down to run it, replace `<your-API-key-here>` with your real API key.

Here's the basic template:

```html
<div ref="mapContainer" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">Google Map will load here</div>
```

And the script tag:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: '<your-API-key-here>',
  libraries: ['places']
})

const map = ref<google.maps.Map>()
const mapContainer = ref<HTMLDivElement>()
const markers = ref<google.maps.Marker[]>([])

onMounted(async () => {
  await loader.load()

  map.value = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer.value as HTMLDivElement, {
    zoom: 4,
    center: { lat: 40, lng: -100 }
  })
})

const clearMarkers = () => {
  markers.value.forEach((marker) => {
    marker.setMap(null)
  })
  markers.value = []
}

const addMarkers = () => {
  const newMarkers = [
    { lat: 37.535916, lng: -96.524573 },
    { lat: 46.021019, lng: -117.147974 },
    { lat: 40.662888, lng: -81.018198 }
  ]

  newMarkers.forEach((marker) => {
    markers.value.push(new google.maps.Marker({ map: map.value, position: marker }))
  })
}
</script>
```

Calling `addMarkers` will display the markers on the map, but calling `clearMarkers` appears to do nothing. Calling `setMap(null)` is how markers should be removed from the map. This works when using plain HTML/JS (following the guide at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map#maps_add_map-css), however, when I stick it into Vue it doesn't work.

What's causing this to not work in Vue?

Comment: `markers.value = []` will remove reactivity of markers on the map. Try this `markers.value.slice(0)`

Comment: @KArslan I think you meant `splice`, not `slice`. And no, refs are mutable so assigning a new value to it will not remove reactivity. I tried it anyway and it made no difference.

Comment: Sorry for that, `Splice`. You're correct that refs are mutable, but in this case, the problem isn't related to reactivity. When you assign an empty array to markers.value, it creates a new array object and replaces the original array object that was being tracked by Vue's reactivity system. However, the original array object that contains the markers is still referenced by the markers themselves and is not destroyed, so the markers still exist on the map. Please try this again, 'markers.value.splice(0, markers.value.length)'

Comment: Seems I'm talking to a ChatGPT bot here. Your account is barely a month old, your reply is exactly what ChatGPT spits out. You contradict yourself and when I corrected you, you had the typical ChatGPT reply of "sorry, you are correct ...".

Comment: ha~, are you sure? anyhow `splice` is working or not?

Comment: `splice` is not working, no, but that did get me to realize that `ref` will wrap it's objects in `reactive` and so even after calling `.value` or `unref`, it's referencing a proxy, not the original/underlying object. Using `shallowRef` solved my problem! ChatGPT or not, thanks!

Comment: My Pleasure! I have gained a deeper understanding of Vue Reactivity. I think, `Vue.set()` can also resolve the issue.